# Why Not To Take B8ZS with encoding 7 digit?

Tags: algorithms, communication-protocols

I have a simple question. In signal encoding we have B8ZS (Bipolar with 8 zeros substitutions) technique which encodes every 8 sequencial 0 bits with 000+-0-+ or 000-+0-+ depends on previous voltage level. Can we do this with 7 seven bits like 0+-+0-+- and 0-+-0+-+ in order to decrease number of 0s and to prevent from dc signal? (Can anybody open a data-communication category for this question? I could not because of the reputation thing, thanks)